# Why is GitHub Pages redirecting me to a weird URL?

Tags: github-pages

While GitHub is successfully publishing my gh-pages branch to github.io, and the URL `<organization>.github.io/<repo>` successfully takes me my pages, GitHub is redirecting the request to a funny, temporary looking host. Examples are like this:

`https://effective-lamp-816e8e33.pages.github.io/`

or

`https://brilliant-avocado-29b3ce22f.pages.io/`

I *can* copy the site to the `<organization>.github.io` repo, and then everything works, but GitHub's auto-publish is *NOT* copying to this repo and results in this weird host name.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I have this same question. I can't the explanation in the docs yet.

Answer (score 2):

I opened a GitHub support case to ask this same question. In short, if you want to control that URL, you must use a custom domain.

In full,
Private GitHub Pages sites are served from a randomly generated domain to prevent attacks where a script on another GitHub Pages site in your organization, which may be a public site, is used to retrieve data from the private site by using the viewer's session cookie that enables access to the private data.

Therefore by isolating private GitHub Pages sites on their own domain, we can remove one vector for attack. While you can't place your private GitHub Pages sites on [account].github.io, you can choose a custom domain for them. Please note that, despite the private URL, if you use your own custom domain, the CNAME record in DNS should still point to [account].github.io.

You can configure your pages site to use a custom domain, please see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site) for more information.

You can also read more about publishing your site [here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site).